# OOP PHP and instantiating classes

Tags: php

I am relatively new to OOP approach to PHP, but just wanted something clarified:

```
if(isset($_POST['insertProduct']) && !empty($_POST['productName'])){
    $newProduct = new product();
    $newProduct->productName = $_POST['productName'];
    $newProduct->servingSize = $_POST['servingSize'];
    $productID = $newProduct->insertProduct();   
}
```

So the above code is executed when a form is posted to the page to enter a new product into the DB.

```
$selectProduct = new product();
if($selectProduct->getProducts()){
    foreach($selectProduct->getProducts() as $product){ 
        echo '<option value="' .
            $product['productID'] . '">' . 
            $product['productName'] . '</option>';
    }
}
```

The above piece is on the same page, and obviously now there are two instances of the product class that exist (assuming the form has been posted to add a new product). Does this show a benefit of the OO approach? As in using two instances to access different methods? Or is it a bad way of doing what I want to do?

Comment: It entirely depends on what the `product` class/object does.

Comment: Right, well because I have recently started doing it, it updates products, get product information, and adds new products. Thats pretty much all it will do

Comment: It ultimately depends on your design patterns. As it is right now, it might get confusing to have the same class represent a product and access a collection of products.

Comment: It looks to me like your "product" class may be trying to do too much. In my personal view, the Product class should be exactly that: the information that belongs to a product, with methods for manipulating them. It *probably* should not contain a method to retrieve a list of products. You could think of a ProductCollection class which would be responsible for obtaining a list of Product entities - this is obviously my personal view. There are many "correct" ways to do something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `getProducts` should be at least a static method, since it doesn't have nothing to do with the instance of a product.
A product class should represent only the single data of a product, therefore generic non-instances methods should be set to static or moved to another class.

I'd suggest you to create a Factory class that will create the `product` instances for you:

```
$array = FactoryProducts::getProducts();
```

But you surely need to move that method outside the `product` class.
For the rest, everything seems fine.